# Debian/Linux Group permissions are not working as they are supposed to

Tags: linux, permissions, debian, usergroups

I'm working on BOINC project.

I have two users: boincadm and www-data (for apache).
Both belong to group boinc

```
www-data : boinc www-data boincadm
boincadm : boinc adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape audio dip www-data video plugdev netdev bluetooth lpadmin fuse scanner sambashare subversion
```

I have a boinc project created in /home/boincadm/projects/myproject/
All files and folders there are owned by boincadm : boinc and have rwxrwx--- permissions.

The problem is that www-data user can not access to files, which causes multiple errors like:

> Warning: require_once(../inc/db.inc): failed to open stream: Permission denied in    /home/boincadm/projects/myproject/html/user/index.php
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../inc/db.inc'  (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in  /home/boincadm/projects/myproject/html/user/index.php

or just

> Can't access the file XXX

in logs..

IF I change grant rwx to "others"  (777) it works..

My question is, why don't the group permissions work as I expect? Any ideas?

I'm not an expert in linux, thus I could miss something.

Comment: Try to log in as www-data and try to access those files manually. At some point in the path the permissions are wrong.

Comment: I can not login as this user.. maybe it's system or something.. This is the user which is created when installing apache2.

Comment: You can, just execute "su www-data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

First of all I read this:
[link](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-tutorial/ch-files.html)
At some point this article mentioned file `/etc/group` whe information about groups is stored.

I opened this file and mentioned that inspite of my previous actions there is no `www-data` in group `boinc`. And no `www-data` in group  `boincadm` and the opposite. That is strange!
Strange because I've added these users to group boinc using `usermod` command and made sure this group is primary for both.
Moreover command `groups <username>` showed that they are in group `boinc`.

So now the question is: **Why this happened?**

The problem was solved by modifying 3 lines:

```
boinc:x:1111:boincadm, www-data
boincadm:x:1112:boincadm, www-data
www-data:x:1113:www-data, boincadm
```

I needed all 3 lines to make it work. Hope it helps somebody. And I still would like to understand why the file `/etc/group` was not modified automatically when using `usermod`. And why grops shows correct result if so.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility:

`www-data` has primary group `www-data`; the rest are [supplementary groups](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/xrat/xbd_chap03.html#tag_01_03_00_56).

The server process has the right user (by [`setresuid`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setresuid.2.html) or similar) and primary group (by [`setresgid`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setresgid.2.html) or similar), but lacks the other supplementary groups (without [`initgroups`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/initgroups.3.html) or similar).

If this is the case, you have a few options: change the file ownership to the primary group, change the group the server runs as, or fix the server to include all supplementary groups.

Comment: I've made sure that the group is primary for both.. I solved finally.. But the question is modified... See my own answer